# Using different themes error on "The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, nopcommerce

Can somebody explain me code below? If i understand correctly, it tell me that if Breadcrumb section is defined, render this section. but it is defined inside the If clause itself already, how does it work? This code is from NopCommerce _ColumnsOne.cshtml. I implementing a plugin and it works fine on default theme but it will give me an error on another theme, telling me "The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered for the layout page "~/Themes/noproot/Views/Shared/_ColumnsOne.cshtml": "Breadcrumb"."

In the other themese _ColumnsOne.cshtml this line doesnt exist indeed. So it looks like below. I am confused why it tries to render this shared view from default theme while I am on other theme.

Standard Theme:

```
    @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Root.cshtml";
}
@if (IsSectionDefined("Breadcrumb"))
{
    @section Breadcrumb {
        @RenderSection("Breadcrumb")
    }
}
<div class="center-1">
    @Html.Widget("main_column_before")
    @RenderBody()
    @Html.Widget("main_column_after")
</div>
```

Other Theme;

```
    @{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Root.cshtml";
}
<div class="">
    @Html.Widget("main_column_before")

    @RenderBody()
    @Html.Widget("main_column_after")
</div>
```

Comment: This is just the definition of the layouts. But you are calling it in the plugin (as you said). So in your plugin you are not checking. Make a check in your plugin view as well.